# Можно ли хранить пароль в сеcсии? (в зашифрованном виде)

Tags: php

Создаю сессию и хочу хранить в ней пароль в зашифрованном виде.

Для чего это нужно?

При каждом действии пользователя проверяется сессия, по этому если пользователь попытается изменить любое значение в сессии, она сразу же прекратится, так же это нужно в случае, если сессия открыта в нескольких браузерах сразу, но в одном из них сменился пароль, а сама сессия закроется нескоро, как итог если пароль был сменён, сессия закроется

Можно ли так делать и правильно ли это?

Comment: Хранить пароль таким образом это уже неправильно. Используйте токены для подобных действий.

Comment: Сессия контролируется сервером, поэтому при смене пароля у пользователя на одном ПК она закрывается на сервере, запрашивая учетные данные на других ПК пользователя. И как вам уже сказали для этого не нужно хранить пароли в сессии, их нужно хранить как хэш на сервере, а хэш нельзя расшифровать обратно.

Comment: Писать в сессию токен, как вариант из логина, пароля, соли (шифрование на ваше усмотрение), так же писать его в базу, организовать метод, который при смене пароля, логина - переписывает токен, сверять его на клиенте с сессионным токеном. Но пароль, даже в виде хэша, не стоит.